# Simple JS function in order to set a list of checked boxes in a form does not work

Tags: javascript, php, html, checkbox

so i'm i'm using basic JS and PHP to write a form. In a that form i have several checkboxes in which the user can click to add it to his object.

```
<div class="input-group input-group-sm">
     <span class="input-group-addon">Tube(s) : </span>
     <input id="tube" name="tube" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ex :TH2132A" style="display:none" required>
</div>
<div style="max-height:150px;overflow:auto;margin:5px;border: 1px solid;">
     <table class="table table-striped" >
       '.$this->tabTubeModif().'
     </table>
</div>
```

As u see i'm calling a function in order to build the table that contains all my checkboxes. This function checks the related object attributes in order to render the correct information in the form.

```
public function tabTubeModif($outil){
    $tubes=type::findAll();
    $res='';
    foreach ($tubes as $tube){
        if (in_array(str_replace(" ","-",$tube->__get("nom")),explode("/",$outil->__get("liste_tubes")))){
            $res .= '<tr><td>' . str_replace(" ", "-", $tube->__get("nom")) . '</td><td><input type="checkbox" id="' . str_replace(" ", "-", $tube->__get("nom")) . '" onchange=editListTube("' . str_replace(" ", "-", $tube->__get("nom")) . '") value="'. str_replace(" ", "-", $tube->__get("nom")) . '" checked="checked" </td></tr>';
        }
        else{
            $res .= '<tr><td>' . str_replace(" ", "-", $tube->__get("nom")) . '</td><td><input type="checkbox" id="' . str_replace(" ", "-", $tube->__get("nom")) . '" onchange=editListTube("' . str_replace(" ", "-", $tube->__get("nom")) . '") value="' . str_replace(" ", "-", $tube->__get("nom")) . '" </td></tr>';
        }
    }
    return $res;
}
```

And onchange of the checkbox i'm calling a js function :

```
function editListTube(id_check){
alert(document.getElementById("tube").value)

var vale="#"+id_check;


if (document.getElementById(id_check).checked){
    alert(vale+'CHECK2');
    if ( document.getElementById("tube").value==''){
        document.getElementById("tube").value+=id_check;
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("tube").value+='/'+id_check;
    }
}

else{
    alert(document.getElementById("tube").value)
    alert(vale+'UNCHECK2');

    var val='';
    var vals = document.getElementById("tube").value.split('/');

    for (var i=0; i<vals.length;i++){
        if (vals[i]==document.getElementById(id_check).value){
            vals.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
    for (var j=0; j<vals.length;j++) {
        if (j==vals.length-1){
            val+=vals[j];
        }
        else{
            val+=vals[j]+'/'
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("tube").value=val;
}
```

}

Basically it is just suppose to add/remove the corresponding string from the hidden text input "tube". But i have 2 problems.

First as you see i set up some alerts in my js function to see in which part of the code i am, and it seems that when the checkbox is checked when the form loads, weather i check or uncheck i always pass by the "uncheck" part of the code...I believe this is due to (in TabTubeModif) the way i check them "checked="checked"" but i can't think of another way to do it.

2nd problem comes on alert(document.getElementById("tube").value) returns empty, when on the page and in the genrated html code it definitely has a value :[image]

So just to sum up my problem :
If a box is checked on the load of form, i uncheck it once, i pass by the good part of my code but the "#tube" field is not updated cause it's value seems empty (when its not in fact). And if i try try to re-check that same box, it goes in the uncheck part of the js code...

Any help appreciated !

Comment: can u provide a running jsfiddle?

Comment: @YanjunLin https://jsfiddle.net/x0qs1gus/ (first time using jsfiddle, is it what u expected?)

Comment: Pleas provide a piece of that code that address the specific problem

Comment: Also my problem occurs on modifying an object, but i have the exact same form and code for creating one and js function works well for both check and uncheck.

Comment: @YaniOz this fiddle is not working, please just show us a working fiddle shows what is not going right